# Comparing list values between two dictionaries that have no matching keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have two dictionaries where they keys won't match, but values will. All values in each dictionary contain 3 list items as ints.

```
dict1 = {'red':[1,2,3],'blue':[2,3,4],'orange':[3,4,5]}

dict2 = {'green':[3,4,5],'yellow':[2,3,4],'red':[5,2,6]}
```

I would like to compare each list and find which two keys have matching value lists. In this case "blue" and "yellow" match, as well as "green" and "orange".

I took a look at this thread but was not able to get it to work, and I'm not exactly sure I'm asking the same thing: [comparing two dictionaries with list type values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062166/comparing-two-dictionaries-with-list-type-values)

I haven't worked with dictionaries before and am not really sure I understand list comprehensions yet, either. (A lot of posts seem to use them)

Comment: What happens if a value is shared between more than two keys (i.e., three colors with the same value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep it nice and simple:

```
dict1 = {'red':[1,2,3],'blue':[2,3,4],'orange':[3,4,5]}

dict2 = {'green':[3,4,5],'yellow':[2,3,4],'red':[5,2,6]}

matches = []
for key1 in dict1:
    for key2 in dict2:
        if dict1[key1] == dict2[key2]:
            matches.append((key1, key2))

print(matches)
```

Output:

```
[('blue', 'yellow'), ('orange', 'green')]
```

Comment: Thanks you! Works great and I understand. Small follow up...if the dictionaries had float values, how could I compare their truncated values?

Comment: No worries man :), yeah so do you mean comparing a values such as `3.75`, and only looking at the leading `3` for comparisons? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Something like `if all(math.abs(v1 - v2) < epsilon for v1, v2 in zip(dict1[key1], dict2[key2]))`.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes, I put up another question for this since pasting the code in comments is kinda nuts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077634/truncate-dictionary-list-values

Comment: yeah no worries @john, I answered the question for you :)

Comment: Did my answer help @john?

Comment: @RoadRunner, it did. Although I needed to trunc, not round or create an int. I made that more explicit in an edit to the question. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah no worries @John, i did my best to my understanding. You would have found one of the other answers more helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension (which is just a shortcut for "for loops"):

```
matching = [(k1, k2) for k1 in dict1 for k2 in dict2 if dict1[k1] == dict2[k2]]
print matching
# [('blue', 'yellow'), ('orange', 'green')]
```

Answer (score -1):

For any case if you don't understand Julien's answer, this doing the same thing.

```
dict1 = {'red':[1,2,3],'blue':[2,3,4],'orange':[3,4,5]}

dict2 = {'green':[3,4,5],'yellow':[2,3,4],'red':[5,2,6]}

for k1,v1 in dict1.items(): #each key and value in dict1
    for k2,v2 in dict2.items(): #each key and value in dict2
        if v1 == v2: #if values match
            print (k1,k2) #print their keys
```

Comment: almost doing the same thing since it only prints the results :-)